# Convert unicode to decimal

Tags: python-3.x, string, unicode, hex, data-conversion

I have a string like this which i want to convert to only decimal data:

```
"\u0006;\u0003\u001588D402"
```

I'm not sure what the output should look like, but I imagine it should be like this:

```
"631588D402"
```

I have tried to separate each hexadecimal data and then join them but have been unable to either separate them or convert them correctly. Any idea?

Comment: You want to remove the ";" from the input string also?

Comment: `[ord(char) for char in mystr]` gives u list of chars, use `"".join([ord(char) for char in mystr])` for a string representing unicode, in your case `[6, 59, 3, 21, 56, 56, 68, 52, 48, 50]`

Comment: Yes, i want to remove ";" from the input string and keep only the number on hexadecimal. @jvx8ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go through the string and **if** the current `char` is a `hex number` you add it to `new_s` **elif** `char` in `string.printable` you skip it (because it is not a hex number and it is printable so it's not some value) **else** you convert `char` to his value and then to hex and add the `hex value` to `new_s`

```
import string


s = "\u0006;\u0003\u001588D402"
new_s = ""
for char in s:
    if char in "0123456789ABCDEF":  # if char is a hex number
        new_s += char
    # the char isn't a hex number and is printable (removes ;)
    elif char in string.printable:
        pass
    else:
        new_s += hex(ord(char))[2:]
# in one line:
# new_s = "".join([char if char in "0123456789ABCDEF" else "" if char in string.printable else hex(ord(char))[2:] for char in s])
print(new_s)
```

Comment: The output is almost what I expected but you forgot to add the ";" in the string, it shows up in the final result and I don't want it. How do i delete it?

Comment: I edited the answer, please look again

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is. Thanks you so much.

Comment: do you need that in 1 line?

Comment: Not really, im just going to create a method that does that so i can call it whenever i want. I prefer it this way so it's more readable. Anyways, if you want to edit the answer and add it would be fine too.